# i got a eclipse neon EE ver. and made a spring project, but it's o stuck like those, 2 errors

Tags: eclipse

2 errors : like this (follow the pict)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIGFd.png)

in a detail.. it's said

1.
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar' in project 'spring' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file spring      Build path  Build Path Problem

2.
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    spring      Unknown Java Problem

i think it's cuz of a wrong path or no jar file

yeah but so what?

could you advice me some steps to solve it? plz...

Answer (score 0):

Check the jar file written in the error message:

> C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar

Is it there? Can you open it manually as a zip?

Occasionally it happens that the jar file is not correctly downloaded from the artifactory (when it happens it usually has 0kb size).

Delete the jar file, and let Maven redownload it again, it usually does the trick.

If it does not solve it, there may be a permission problem (does Eclipse has right to write under that path?), or an artifactory problem (are you using the central repository?) or even antivirus could block the download.